# Can Nginx redirect or rewrite URLs starting with "?" without using an "if" directive?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, joomla

I have an RSS feed `example.com/?format=feed&amp;type=rss` from an old Joomla install. The site is now built with Jekyll, and uses a new URL `example.com/rss.xml` for the RSS feed.

Rewrite rules aren't working for me since the URL starts with "?". I've got it working with an if directive but [want to avoid using if](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Here's the working if directive which I want to replace with a rewrite or redirect:

```
if ($args ~ "type=rss") {
rewrite ^ https://example.com/rss.xml? permanent;
}
```

**Can the if directive for the URL starting with "?" be replaced with a rewrite or redirect?**

Comment: "There are cases where you simply cannot avoid using an if, for example if you need to test a variable which has no equivalent directive." But I would prefer to check `$arg_type = rss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alexyten is right. In this case there is no other way to handle this as what you are trying to match is actually not part of the location but it is rather a GET argument. And, also, as alexeyten suggested, I would use `if ($arg_argname = "exact string")`. Regular expressions have both a performance overhead as well as if they are not correctly written they can lead to unexplained redirects and rewrites.

For example, if you want to match the fact that the `format` parameter has the value `feed`, you would need to do something like this: `if ($arg_format = "feed")`.